# Counting the number of occurence of a word that appears between the same patterns in a txt file

Tags: java

I have a txt file with specific same lines (pattern, AAAAAAA in this example) appearing certain number of times. I want to count the number of 1 that appears between every 2 patterns, that is, even if it appears multiple times between the two patterns, I count it one time. Example: my file looks like below.
The returned result should be 2 because between each AAAAAAA 1 appeared 2 times.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
AAAAAAA
0
0
1
AAAAAAA
0
0
AAAAAAA
1
0
1
```

Comment: What have you tried, please add your code to the question. Why 2 as the result, the last digits comes after the last pattern not between?

Comment: Thanks @Joakim Danielson, yes the last one always doesn't come between! Sorry. I tried some code with Pattern and Matcher but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the broken code? Generally, we like to see the what you've tried, so we can help you learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Java FileReader and parse each line.
If you find the String you are looking for ("AAAAAA" in your example) you start a new block and in each block you check if you find at least one 1. If you do, you increase the counter by one and then return the value after you checked all lines. If you really only want to count a 1 if it is BETWEEN two "AAAAAA" (in your example you also counted the last one) then you need to remove the adding in the end (see my comments in the code)

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    //call the function that calculates the output and give it the path of the textfile to be used
    System.out.println(getNrOfOnesBetweenString("enterPathToYourTextFileHere.txt"));

  }

  private static Integer getNrOfOnesBetweenString(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {

  //store whether we found a 1 in this block
  Boolean oneFoundInThisBlock = false ;
  //this is the counter for the output we want to return
  Integer numberOfBlocksWithOne = 0 ;
  //this is the string between which we want to search a 1
  String stringToSearch = "AAAAAAA";

  //read the file
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

  try {

    String line;

    //foreach line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

      //check if this line contains the string to search for
      if(line.equals(stringToSearch)) {
        //if yes: start a new block
        if(oneFoundInThisBlock) {
          //if there was a 1 since the last occurrence of stringToSearch, increase the counter
          numberOfBlocksWithOne++;
        }
        //reset for next block
        oneFoundInThisBlock = false;
      }
      //see if this line has a 1
      if (line.contains("1")){
        oneFoundInThisBlock = true;
      }
    }

    // add one for the last block -> remove this if you only want to count 1 if they are BETWEEN two "AAAAAA" (in your example you also counted the last one after so not sure what you need)
    if(oneFoundInThisBlock){
      numberOfBlocksWithOne++;
    }
  } catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Could not read from file "+filePath);
  }
  return numberOfBlocksWithOne;
  }
}
```

This would give you the following values:

Example 1:

```
AAAAAAA
0
0
1
AAAAAAA
0
0
AAAAAAA
1
0
1
```

Output (Example 1): 2

Example 2:

```
AAAAAAA
0
AAAAAAA
0
AAAAAAA
1
AAAAAAA
1
AAAAAAA
1
```

Output (Example 2): 3

Example 3:

```
AAAAAAA
0
0
0
AAAAAAA
0
1
AAAAAAA
1
1
AAAAAAA
1
1
1
AAAAAAA
1
1
1
```

Output (Example 3): 4

Comment: the numberOfBlocksWithOne count will need to be reset to zero for each block too

Comment: As I understood the question it shouldn't reset because that's the number the Poster wants in the end

Comment: Can you explain your code? If you just dump in a block of code, you facilitate people just copying & pasting some code form the web, without understanding it, and without learning. See also [answer].

Comment: @Robert I tried to comment in the code what I am doing but I can try to describe it outside of the code as well

Comment: Thanks a lot @juliette